# Deploy Java webapp with Azure

Tags: java, azure, continuous-deployment

I'm new to Azure. I deployed simple webapp, everything ok. When I deploy maven webapp using war file (spring mvc, hibernate), I have this log in my App Service Editor

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 212992 bytes for card table expansion
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   The process is running with CompressedOops enabled, and the Java Heap may be blocking the growth of the native heap
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
#   JVM is running with Unscaled Compressed Oops mode in which the Java heap is
#     placed in the first 4GB address space. The Java Heap base address is the
#     maximum limit for the native heap growth. Please use -XX:HeapBaseMinAddress
#     to set the Java Heap base and to place the Java Heap above 4GB virtual address.
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_windows.cpp:3415), pid=8336, tid=0x0000000000004c6c
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment () (8.0_202-b05) (build 1.8.0_202-b05)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.202-b05 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Failed to find MiniDumpWriteDump() in module dbghelp.dll
#
```

Sometime, Azure return 502 page, or infinity loading page with

```
The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.
```

Azure using window machine, free tier F1, Java 8, Java container: Tomcat

How to solve this problem, tks!!!

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this updating a legacy application or creating a new one?

Comment: This is new webapp :(

Comment: Then I very strongly recommend that you get rid of the war; the recommendation has been to make deployable jars with Boot for about 6 years now. In addition to just making life easier generally, it makes debugging deployment like this easier.

Comment: Tks, I will use boot, but this project must be war (requirement from teacher) :((((

Comment: You may need to share a sample that can reproduce your issue so that others can help you further.

Comment: I created Linux machine and everything work, Window is big problem